# Windows 2003 freezes and restarts without reason

Tags: windows

My Windows server 2003 standard has lately same problems with stability and one in two weeks it stops with BSOD and restarts. I really dont know wheres the problem. RAID seems to be ok. Please help how to diagnose the problem and how to prevent it
Thank you

Here is dump report

Dump File : Mini081811-01.dmp

Crash Time : 18.8.2011 8:40:03

Bug Check String : KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED

Bug Check Code : 0x1000008e

Parameter 1 : 0xc0000005

Parameter 2 : 0x8093b95b

Parameter 3 : 0xf2983a3c

Parameter 4 : 0x00000000

Caused By Driver : hal.dll

Caused By Address : hal.dll+6456

File Description : Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL

Product Name : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

Company : Microsoft Corporation

File Version : 5.2.3790.3959 (srv03_sp2_rtm.070216-1710)

Processor : 32-bit

Computer Name :

Full Path : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\Mini081811-01.dmp

Processors Count : 2

Major Version : 15

Minor Version : 3790

==================================================

---

This is the result of my debug:

MODULE_NAME: nt

FAULTING_MODULE: 80800000 nt

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4cbda48f

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Instrukce na adrese 0x%08lx odkazovala na adresu pam

FAULTING_IP:
nt+13b95b
8093b95b 8b4e1c          mov     ecx,dword ptr [esi+1Ch]

TRAP_FRAME:  f32afa3c -- (.trap 0xfffffffff32afa3c)
ErrCode = 00000000
eax=f32afbb4 ebx=8907fd70 ecx=8b581ca0 edx=00000000 esi=00000001 edi=00000000
eip=8093b95b esp=f32afab0 ebp=f32afb88 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na pe nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010286
nt+0x13b95b:
8093b95b 8b4e1c          mov     ecx,dword ptr [esi+1Ch] ds:0023:0000001d=????????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT_SERVER_MINIDUMP

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x8E

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 8094acdb to 8093b95b

STACK_TEXT:
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
f32afb88 8094acdb 8907fd88 f32afbb4 001f0fff nt+0x13b95b
f32afce4 8094afff 0176f3fc 001f0fff 00000000 nt+0x14acdb
f32afd38 808897ec 0176f3fc 001f0fff 00000000 nt+0x14afff
f32afd64 7e05847c badb0d00 0176f040 00000000 nt+0x897ec
f32afd68 badb0d00 0176f040 00000000 00000000 0x7e05847c
f32afd6c 0176f040 00000000 00000000 00000000 0xbadb0d00
f32afd70 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x176f040

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP:
nt+13b95b
8093b95b 8b4e1c          mov     ecx,dword ptr [esi+1Ch]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt+13b95b

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_NAME:  ntoskrnl.exe

BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

Followup: MachineOwner

I thought, this problem makes RAM. I have changed it, but problem is still there

Could this be done by some rootkit? 
Harddrive has no errors and is in mirror raid

Answer (score 1):

[Set your server to do some sort of dump](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254649).

[Use `windbg` to read and diagnose the problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263).